# std::string constructor corrupts pointer

Tags: c++, string, macos, memory-corruption

I have an Entity class, which contains 3 pointers: m_rigidBody, m_entity, and m_parent. Somewhere in Entity::setModel(std::string model), it's crashing. Apparently, this is caused by bad data in m_entity. The weird thing is that I nulled it in the constructor and haven't touched it since then. I debugged it and put a watchpoint on it, and it comes up that the m_entity member is being changed in the constructor for std::string that's being called while converting a const char* into an std::string for the setModel call. I'm running on a Mac, if that helps (I think I remember some problem with std::string on the Mac). Any ideas about what's going on?

EDIT: Here's the code for GEntity:

```
GEntity::GEntity(GWorld* world, unsigned long int idNum) {
    GEntity(world, idNum, btTransform::getIdentity());
}

GEntity::GEntity(GWorld* world, unsigned long int idNum, btTransform trans) : m_id(idNum), m_trans(trans), m_world(world) {
    // Init unused properties
    m_rigidBody = NULL;
    m_entity = NULL; // I'm setting it here
    m_parent = NULL;

    // Find internal object name
    std::ostringstream ss;
    ss << "Entity" << idNum << "InWorld" << world;
    m_name = ss.str();

    // Create a scene node
    m_sceneNode = m_world->m_sceneMgr->getRootSceneNode()->createChildSceneNode(m_name+"Node");

    // Initialize the SceneNode's transformation
    m_sceneNode->setPosition(bv3toOv3(m_trans.getOrigin()));
    m_sceneNode->setOrientation(bqToOq(m_trans.getRotation()));
}

void GEntity::setModel(std::string model) {
    m_model = model;

    // Delete entity on model change
    if(m_entity != NULL) { // And by the time this line comes around, it's corrupt
            m_world->m_sceneMgr->destroyEntity(m_entity);
            m_entity = NULL;
    }

    // Create new entity with given model
    m_entity = m_world->m_sceneMgr->createEntity(m_name+"Ent", model);

    // Apply a new rigid body if needed
    if(m_rigidBody != NULL) {
            initPhysics();
    }
}
void GEntity::initPhysics() {
    deinitPhysics();
}

void GEntity::deinitPhysics() {
    if(m_rigidBody != NULL) {
        m_world->m_dynWorld->removeRigidBody(m_rigidBody);
        delete m_rigidBody;
        m_rigidBody = NULL;
    }
}
```

And here's the definition of GEntity:

```
class GEntity : public btMotionState {
public:
    GEntity(GWorld* world, unsigned long int idNum);
    GEntity(GWorld* world, unsigned long int idNum, btTransform trans);
    void setModel(std::string modelName);
    void initPhysics();
    void deinitPhysics();
    void getWorldTransform(btTransform& worldTrans) const;
    void setWorldTransform(const btTransform &trans);
    void parent(GEntity* parent);
protected:
    unsigned long int m_id;

    // Physics representation
    btTransform m_trans;
    btRigidBody* m_rigidBody;

    // Graphics representation
    Ogre::SceneNode* m_sceneNode;
    Ogre::Entity* m_entity;

    // Engine representation
    GWorld* m_world;
    GEntity* m_parent;
    std::string m_name;
    std::string m_model; // Used to find physics collision mesh
};
```

And here's the code calling setModel:

```
// Setup game world
GWorld* world = new GWorld(win);
GEntity* ent = world->createEntity();
ent->setModel(std::string("Cube.mesh"));
```

Comment: It would help if you code post code that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Work from the assumption that the std::string constructor does *not* have a bug.  Search these forums or Google "heap corruption".

Comment: I'm betting that there's no bug in std::string constructor but there is a huge bug in your code ...

Comment: I think that as a bare minimum you need to post the definition of `GEntity` that the code which is calling `setModel`; ideally a minimal complete compilable program that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Print the value out to console. I have learnt not to trust the Xcode debugger (particularly with strings) the hard way.

Comment: The string you think is being modified.

Comment: I don't think the string is being modified. m_entity is getting corrupted somewhere in the string constructor.

Comment: umm, m_entity is an Ogre::Entity* and m_rigidBody is a btRigidBody*

Comment: What about the definition of `GWorld`, `GWorld::GWorld` and `GWorld::createEntity`. Oh and what is `win`?

Comment: win is an Ogre::RenderWindow*

Comment: Dang! I had misread `m_entity` as a `string`.

Comment: OK, what about the definition of the GEntity constructor that is actually used (i.e. the one that takes two parameters, not three).

Comment: that just calls the 3-param constructor with btTransform::getIdentity() as the third param

Comment: when I replace the 2-param call in GWorld::createEntity, it works fine

Comment: You can't call a constructor for the same object from another constructor. Please post exactly what the two parameter constructor is doing.

Comment: Finally, we get to see where the error is!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that this line is constructing a nameless temporary `GEntity` inside the constructor body for a different `GEntity`. The temporary is then thrown away once the statement completes and no further initialization of the non-temporary GEntity is performed.

```
GEntity(world, idNum, btTransform::getIdentity());
```

If you want to share some initialization code between your two constructors you should create a member function that performs the required actions and call this function from both constructors. C++ doesn't (currently) allow you to delegate initialization from one constructor to a different constructor or call two constructors on the same object.

Comment: Now that we see this constructor, that seem obvious!
Constructor calling on the same class will not be available until C++0x is out.

Comment: thanks. I thought C++ would have that from time spent coding Objective-C.

Answer (score 2):

My best guess is that the problem is in **GWorld::createEntity**.  If you're creating a local **GEntity** on the stack and returning a pointer to it, you'll see something like what you describe, as the **GEntity** is destroyed when **GWorld::createEntity** returns and the memory is reused for the temp string constructed to pass to **setModel**

**Edit**

I see you've added more code, including the definition of **createEntity**.  That looks fine, but I would still suggest looking for some way in which the GEntity you're seeing the problem with gets deleted (and the memory reused for a string) before you call setModel.

Answer (score 1):

One solution I have found is to use `string.resize(n)`, which will resize the function. However, I do not know why this works, and I feel my problem is with my code since `std::string` is part of the standard C++ library.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find the answer but I can make a suggestion that will help catch the problem:

**Add assertions.** A lot of assertions. Each one of those functions really need some assertions at least at their beginning. That will certainly help you catch wrong states early.

And by the way, you should use a constant reference as parameter of your setModel() function.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ you can not call a constructor from within a constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Try

`GEntity::GEntity(GWorld* world, unsigned long int idNum) : GEntity(world, idNum, btTransform::getIdentity() {}`